# MethodInfo GetBaseDefinition() method not working with generic base types

Tags: c#, reflection

```
class Program
{
    class Example : List<Type> { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var mi = typeof(Example).GetMethod("IndexOf", new Type[] { typeof(Type), typeof(int) });
        var realMi = MyFunction(mi);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Initial definition: {0}", mi));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Base definition: {0}", mi.GetBaseDefinition()));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("MyFunction Result: {0}", realMi));

        var tType1 = typeof(List<>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Goal Example 1: {0}",
            typeof(List<>).GetMethod("IndexOf", new Type[] { tType1, typeof(int) })));

        var tType2 = mi.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetGenericArguments()[0];
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Goal Example 2: {0}",
            mi.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetMethod("IndexOf",
                new Type[] { tType2, typeof(int) })));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static MethodInfo MyFunction(MethodInfo mi)
    {
        // what code should be there???            
        return mi.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().GetMethod("IndexOf",
            mi.GetParameters().Select(p => p.GetType()).ToArray());
    }
}
```

How to get the Goal from MyFunction?

Console output:

```
Initial definition: Int32 IndexOf(System.Type, Int32)
Base definition: Int32 IndexOf(System.Type, Int32)
MyFunction Result:
Goal Example 1: Int32 IndexOf(T, Int32)
Goal Example 2: Int32 IndexOf(T, Int32)
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what you expect where, and what you're getting. What do you *want* `MyFunction` to return? Please add more text to the question to clarify it...

Comment: Console output added. MyFunction returns null instead of goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
static MethodInfo MyFunction(MethodInfo mi) {
    Type listT = mi.DeclaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    MethodInfo miListT = (MethodInfo)MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(mi.MethodHandle, listT.TypeHandle);
    return miListT;
}
```

You can use the same "trick" to go from `List<X1>.IndexOf` → `List<Y1>.IndexOf`, `List<>.IndexOf` → `List<X1>.IndexOf`, `List<X1>.IndexOf` → `List<>.IndexOf`.